# How to remove div tag?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a plugin that allows me to remove the style from the div.
I would like to remove the div tag too.

For the moment the plugin realizes this action :

```
<div class="GCO9_TDM"><p>text</p></div>  --> <div><p>text</p></div>
```

This is the code of my plugin :

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'supprimerDivision', {
icons: 'supprimerDivision',
    init: function( editor ) {

        editor.addCommand( 'supprimerDivision', {
            exec: function( editor ) {

                var element = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
                    while (element) {
                        if (element.getName() == 'div') {
                            element.setAttribute('class', '');
                            break;
                        }

                        element = element.getParent();
                    }   
            }
        });
                
        editor.ui.addButton( 'supprimerDivision', {
            label: 'supprime la division',
            command: 'supprimerDivision',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        } );
     }
});
```

Thanks, have a good day.

**EDIT :** my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <title>Editeur</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> <!-- emplacement de ckeditor -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="enregistrementBDD.php" method="post">
            <textarea id="editor" name="editor">      

            </textarea>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {     //remplace le textarea par une instance de ckeditor 
                        height: 600,              //taille de la fênetre

                        allowedContent: true, //permet de définir des règles de contenu autorisé (true désactive le filtre)

                        //startupOutlineBlocks: true, //autorise le plugin showblock a être actif dès le lancement

                        toolbarCanCollapse: true, //permet de cacher la barre d'outil via un bouton situé en bas à droite des menus


                        extraPlugins: 'espace,'+
                        'ckeditor_wiris,'+
                        'dropdownmenumanager,'+

                        'raccourciClavier,'+
                        'supprimerStyle,'+
                        'supprimerDivision,'+

                        

                        'GCO12_DocIll,'+
                        'SLT2_Num_XXX1_DocIll,'+
                        'STI1_Titre_XXX1_DocIll',

                        //fullPage: true, //page HTML complète avec balise <html>, <head>, <body>...
                } );
            </script>
        </form> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already tried this code but it works now, here is the solution

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'supprimerDivision', {
icons: 'supprimerDivision',
    init: function( editor ) {

        editor.addCommand( 'supprimerDivision', {
            exec: function( editor ) {

                var element = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
                    while (element) {
                        if (element.getName() == 'div') {
                            element.setAttribute('class', '');
                            element.remove("div");
                            break;
                        }

                        element = element.getParent();
                    }   
            }
        });
                
        editor.ui.addButton( 'supprimerDivision', {
            label: 'supprime la division',
            command: 'supprimerDivision',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        } );
     }
});
```